# Can the ECS pipe/hose run through the aircraft fuel tank?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, fuel-systems, fuel-tanks, hydraulic-system

Hope you can help?

We are in the process of redefining aircraft fuel tank and there might be a possibility that we may need to run the ECS (Environmental control system) pipe through the fuel tank? Would that be not possible (due to its size in diameter, thermal insulation, etc)?
The same question goes for electrical wiring routes and the hydraulic lines? I understand that there are rules of segregating those, but what could happen if they are all installed in the tank?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Electrical circuitry running through fuel tanks has been known to cause at least one catastrophic disaster - [TWA flight 800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWA_Flight_800). A short circuit likely ignited fuel vapor in the central tank

> The four-year NTSB investigation concluded with the approval of the Aircraft Accident Report on August 23, 2000, ending the most extensive, complex and costly air disaster investigation in U.S. history at that time.[7][8] The report's conclusion was that the probable cause of the accident was explosion of flammable fuel vapors in the center fuel tank. Although it could not be determined with certainty, the likely ignition source was a short circuit.[1]: xvi  Problems with the aircraft's wiring were found, including evidence of arcing in the fuel quantity indication system (FQIS) wiring that enters the tank.

Comment: So just to clarify, what I take away from this answer is, “Yes, you can run electrical circuitry through fuel tanks.”

Comment: @Jim It was specifically in answer to (emphasis mine) _"I understand that there are rules of segregating those, but what **could** happen if they are all installed in the tank?"_